# Sudden shift in this conversation

Tags: topic

> MC:「部活か？　夏休み中なのにお前の調理部午前中から張り切りすぎだろ」
>
> 妹:「部活は部活だけど、最近はウチ料理しないで手芸部と化してるから。今みんなで羊毛フェルトにハマってるの」

Context: breakfast table, mc, and his sister and parents

I'm having a hard time relating not cooking at home with a change to an arts and crafts club, let alone why everyone is a fit for wool felt.

After this his sister just says goodbye and leaves.

What is she trying to say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- She confirmed she was going to do "club activities of 調理部" in this morning.
- But the club members no longer do cooking these days, and they are now virtually 手芸部. (**EDIT**: This うち is an informal way of saying "our club (or office/team/class/etc)")
- *Therefore, what she is actually going to do in the morning is not 調理 but 手芸.*

The part after から has been omitted, but the omitted final part is the main implication of her first sentence. (But how did you come up with "not cooking *at home*"? Is the club activity going to take place in their home, or did she refuse to prepare breakfast this day?)

This ～にハマる means "to be caught up in ～" or "to devote oneself in ～".

Comment: home was the first thing i thought of. She cooked breakfast that morning. i think the entire statement is more whimsical than anything else now that i look at it